# have over 8GB free disk and "disk full" message appears

Tags: hard-drive, performance, macbook

my macbook pro

- System Version: 10.9.5
- Processor:  2.9 GHz Intel Core i7
- Hard Disk: 250 GB
- Memory: 8 GB
- Number of Processors:   1
- Total Number of Cores:  2
- L2 Cache (per Core):    256 KB
- L3 Cache:   4 MB

has currently 8+GB of free disk space, while working these symptoms appear:

- the computers slows down dramatically
- the disk space is running out
- "your startup disk is full" message appears

restarting the computer "fix" the problem but the symptoms appear faster from day to day

- running ClamXav didn't find a virus.
- finger shows I'm the only user logged in
- working apps usualy include: xcode + simulator, notes, textwrangler, finder, pixelmator, chrome

help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah;  You need to have more than 8GB free on your hDD.

Comment: @Ramhound more than 8 **GB**? sounds wrong that's a lot of free space! how much you think it needs to run properly?

Comment: Absolute minimum 5%. Aim for 15% as a better working guide.